# Difference between allow write and allow create update in Firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Could anyone tell me what is the difference between `allow write` and `allow create update` in writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation for [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

`write` is exactly equivalent to the combination of `create`, `update`, and `delete`.  If you allow `write`, you are implicitly allowing all three more specific permissions.   If you allow only `create` and `update`, it does not allow documents to be deleted.